# Jquery autocomplete is not working when accessed from different server

Tags: jquery, asp.net, autocomplete

We are using a jquery autocomplete function in an HTML page for the type ahead in textbox. 
We are using a JQuery which calls a .net page which interns calls the service and returns JSON. 
The problem here is this works when all of them are in same server.
But our requirement is as such that the HTML page is in different server and the .net page it is calling is in different server.

I have hosted the .net page in IIS in one server and the HTML page's Jquery calls this hosted page. When it goes through IIS it give an error "ACCESS IS DENIED".
I think it is due to IIS different security level settings.

When i open it locally the IE asks for "allow blocked content" w.r.t to Active X control and when i accept it starts working, but through IIS i don't get this allow blocked content in IE.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        type: "POST"
    });
    $('input[type=text][id$=txtTest]').autocomplete("server/testpage", {
        dataType: "json",
        minChars: 2,
        datakey: "JsonExam",
        max: 10,
        width: 605,
        formatItem: function(item) {
            return item.Name;
        },
        useValidation: true
    });
})​;​
```

Comment: which jquery autocomplete plugin are you using? doesn't look like jquery ui autocomplete.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that Ajax call are only allowed on the same domain (see same origin policy: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy ). You can't call a service on another server, except if you are using JSONP.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Fox32 that you can't make remote calls with ajax. Try JQuery UI Autocomplete it has JSONP support. Check demo at http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/remote-jsonp.html